# Reading in from Text File, Mismatch Exception (When reading in Float)

Tags: java, exception

I'm having issues reading a Float in from an external data file (.txt)
I've read a number of different posts about this error, and common problems, and I still don't know what I'm doing wrong. The advice varies, some people say use ".nextLine()", some people say use ".next()", I've tried a bunch of these combinations and am still having problems.

Here's the relevant section:

```
  public void read_file(Interface iface) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int readCount = 0;

    File file = new File(""); \\FILE PATH REDACTED
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);

    reader.useDelimiter(",|\\n");

    while(reader.hasNext()){

      String type = reader.next();
      float rate = reader.nextFloat();
      String desc = reader.next();

//Some irrelevant code follows
```

Text file:

```
Test1
10.00
Test2
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Scanner.java:2496)
    at ReadFile.read_file(ReadFile.java:20)
    at Main.main(Main.java:21)
```

I conducted a test and it definitely reads in the first line (I was able to print that). So I'm guessing its something to do with the line return at the end of the line after Test1. But I thought that would get handled by the use of the delimiter.

I'm using IntelliJ (some people have suggested that using a ,(comma) instead of a .(period) can sometimes resolve the error - but this seems limited to NetBeans or Eclipse, I forget).

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the line breaks you set in 'reader.useDelimiter()' should be consistent with the line breaks in the file. Generally, it is '\r\n' for Windows, '\n' for Unix, and '\r' for Mac.I hope it can help you.

Comment: Minor mistake : '\r' is for Classic Mac OS only; macOS 10.0+ uses '\n' as any other Unix/Unix-like :)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you must add this line before or after `useDelimiter` :

```
reader.useLocale(Locale.US);
```

It's required for the scanner to be able to detect floats.

---

For whatever reason, once it started working, I tried removing the line and it kept working. I reverted back to your original script, and it was still working. I think the Locale settings are persistent or something.

Anyways, if adding this line works, I suggest leaving it like that :)

Comment: Hello - I tried both before and after, and neither worked unfortunately. Same error on the same float read. Was that all you changed and everything worked fine?

Comment: I copy-pasted your code in an new empty project, I copy-pasted the contents of your file, and it runs like a charm. I can swear a few minutes ago, I had the exact same error you had. I only have one theory at the moment : do you have a trailing newline in your text file? If so, delete it, and make sure you have exactly three lines in total (no empty line at the end).

Comment: Dang - definitely still doesn't work for me, and no trailing new line at the end of the file.

Comment: Well... I'm out of ideas for the moment, my apologies! I'll keep thinking and playing around with it, if I can reproduce that error again I'll carefully note my entire configuration and precisely write down everything I do from there on :) Meanwhile you can try akstianye's answer, though I doubt that's the problem since I had the error and I'm running *nix.

Comment: Thank you, I think it was a minor syntax thing, someone below suggested changing my delimiter and it worked right away. Though it might've also been a combination of needing the Locale. So thank you as well.